# Trying to use JWT token with Azure Function V4

Tags: jwt, azure-functions, identity

I am seeing so many posts with homegrown solutions of forcing AzureFunctions to authenticate based on JWT tokens.  What SHOULD work in v4?

I have my standard (aka works with APIs) section of

```
           .AddJwtBearer(OktaDefaults.ApiAuthenticationScheme, options =>
           {...  }
```

Should the [Authorize] work now?  Or do I have to create custom middleware or just a custom hook to invoke the middleware?

Answer (score 0):

Use this package [Darkloop.Azure.Functions.Authorize](https://blog.darkloop.com/post/functionauthorize-for-azure-functions-v3): It's built on top of the same aspnetcore auth modules already loaded in azure functions, but makes sure your custom authentication will not affect Azure's list access to your functions to be managed in the portal.

It gives you `FunctionAuthorizeAttribute` which you use exactly as you would `AuthorizeAttribute` in WebAPI.

The package is compatible with latest Azure Functions versions, except isolated.